# are there PCI DSS (or equivalent) requirements for user-interface security for cardholders?

Tags: passwords, pci-dss

The PCI DSS requirements around account security (password strength, password changes, etc.) all seem to apply to system users who have access to cardholder data.

Are there any industry standards that apply to the user (i.e. cardholder) accounts themselves?

In other words, suppose I find out that my banking website allows me to set my user account password to "dog".  Is there some banking-specific industry regulation that this violates, that I can point them to?

Comment: What area are you in? Different areas have different banking requirements.

Comment: PCI-DSS Requirement 8 deals with identification and authentication and applies to system users not "consumer users", which is what you are talking about.

Comment: @schroeder yes that's what I said in my question -- what I'm asking about is whether there are also industry standards that apply to the passwords for the consumer-user accounts.

Comment: @schroeder take my bank First Tech Federal as an example, where I'm a normal consumer and I have a checking account and savings account.  If they allow me to set my user password to "dog" (they don't, but let's just say), is there an industry standard that they're violating?

Comment: If your question is if there is a regulation, somewhere, that they are violating, then this question might be too broad.